# is upgrade ubunto 19.10 to 20.04 now not available on ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, 19.10

is upgrade ubunto 19.10 to 20.04 now not available on ubuntu 19.10?

I'm keep getting error when I'm doing

```
sudo apt-get update -y

 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
```

is it cause ubuntu 19.10 does not supported no more?
How should I upgrade 19.10 to 20.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release).  FYI: `sudo apt-get update` only updates the list of available software. It doesn't actually update any packages, much less upgrade to the next release.  You shouldn't wait until *after* a release goes EOL to upgrade. If you don't want to have to upgrade your release every 6 months, I suggest staying with an LTS release.

Comment: Is your system fully-upgraded?   Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades as **after** a release goes EOL, it's repositories are moved (which can occur quickly, mirrors can *drop* an EOL release). This change is manual as it's expected users will *release-upgrade* prior to the EOL occurring (notice was given if you were watching).  Refer the release notes for 20.04 (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes) in the *Upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or 19.10* section for upgrade instructions. They were intended to be used before 19.10 reached EOL though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Ubuntu 19.10 is not supported anymore. You could change the repos in `/etc/apt/sources.list` from `eoan` to `focal` but that might be risky if your system crashes halfway. Or you could follow the guide at [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release). The guide might be outdated. I did the first method and it worked fine.

Comment: That's treating Ubuntu like it's Debian but it's not.  Maybe as a last-option, but it wouldn't be my first. The release notes for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes) have a fully *tested* and *supported* upgrade path/tool which is what I'd try first. Yes if repositories have moved, you'll have to follow the clues from your used link, or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades first .. but I'd not treat Ubuntu like it's Debian unless it's the last trick in the toolbox (it can lead to issues esp. with python)  Upgrade via re-install is easy for desktops.

Comment: I keep getting this message Err:23 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.123 80]
Err:24 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubu

Comment: try to follow this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: @jakeMonk the *eoan* repositories haven't yet moved to old-releases so it doesn't yet need to be done. The official pages don't have a specific date when that occurs, except they state **after** the release reaches EOL (not how long after).  As well mirrors & 3rd parties can drop support anytime **after** the release reaches EOL.